# Do we need class_name and foreign_key declarations in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Do we need class_name and foreign_key declarations in the model class of a rails3 application.

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :user_foos, :class_name => 'UserFoo', :foreign_key => :user_foo_id
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, not if the table name is `user_foos` and the class name is `UserFoo`.  You can simply do:

```
has_many :user_foos
```

The `:class_name` modifier is used where the class name isn't actually the singular of the association name being used, or where namespacing cause the class name to be resolved incorrectly.  And `:foreign_key` is used where the foreign-key column name uses a specialized format (this usually occurs when referencing a row in the same table, or where several columns point to different records of the same parent table).